# Alternative for twoside

Tags: double-sided

I'm using the report class and would like an alternative to the option "twoside". I want chapters and top level TOC-elements to start on right hand pages, but I don't want any of the other, layout molesting, stuff that comes with twoside.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, leqno]{report}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`twoside` really doesn't affect very much. It gives the oportunity to have different margins and headers on odd and even pages, and is detected by `\cleardoublepage` but that is about it.

Your comment about "layout molesting, stuff " isn't very specific but I infer that you want the margins, and perhaps the headings to be the same, so you can put this in the preamble, which just restores the oneside settings from report class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, openright]{report}

\makeatletter
    \setlength\@tempdima        {\paperwidth}
    \addtolength\@tempdima      {-\textwidth}
    \setlength\oddsidemargin    {.5\@tempdima}
    \addtolength\oddsidemargin  {-1in}
    \setlength\marginparwidth   {.5\@tempdima}
    \addtolength\marginparwidth {-\marginparsep}
    \addtolength\marginparwidth {-0.4in}
    \addtolength\marginparwidth {-.4in}
    \setlength\evensidemargin\oddsidemargin

  \def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}\let\@evenhead\@oddhead
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}

\makeatother
```

Comment: Margins and other alignments are still affected.

Comment: I just set evensidemargin to oddsidemargin can't see what else could be different.

Comment: Sorry, I had a conflict with some \newpage-s that made a lot of the mess.

Comment: Combined with 'twoside' and 'openright' in the documentclass, this works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

If by "molesting stuff" you mean different margins on odd and even pages, this will do what you need:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hratio=1:1,textwidth=345pt}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\kant
\chapter{B}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

The second chapter will start on page 5, leaving page 4 empty. If you also need headers, I suggest using `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the workings of `\cleardoublepage` you can define the following command:

```
\makeatletter
\def\nextOnRight{\clearpage \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

Then use `\nextOnRight` before the elements you want to open on the right page. This little hack is needed because `\cleardoublepage` only does its job if `twoside` option is used (if not, it simply issues a `\clearpage`)

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: But this is basically what I'm after.

Comment: @Man Can you provide a minimal (not) working example?